# Is there any criteria to judge a website is blank and has no content using Java?

Tags: java, html, web-crawler

My problem is as follows. Currently I`m doing a web crawling project for my final year. I want to crawl down web pages carrying out **.org** domains and archive for text mining. Having said about the background.

During the crawling process number of blank **.org** domain carrying websites also were detected. Is there any criteria we could use to refrain from crawling web sites having **no content**?

Currently I am passing the URL and it reads the URLs `HTML` content in `Java`. Although websites do not carry any content, still it has `HTML` code. So could you please suggest me a way of doing it?

I have tried figuring out text availability, image availability but it was not possible to stop 100% blank web pages detection.

Comment: I guess you would need a more specific definition of what constitutes "content" first. Do you just mean sites that have more than just <body>&nbsp;</body> or something else. My first step would be to define in code terms what does and does not constitute "content" on a site, then write your code around that.

Comment: @RussJ Content as in anything would be fine in the body section unless when viewing the URL shows blank (just white website).

Comment: Well even there, there are multiple possibilities for showing blank pages. <body></body>, <body>&nbsp;</body>,<body><p></p><body> would all render a blank page, which means you would have to check for all of these possibilities somehow.

Comment: Maybe employ an OCR somehow to detect if there are any characters rendered on the page?

Comment: @RussJ So basically what u mean is to convert the webpage into PDF and using OCR scan for content ? Something like that process ?

Comment: Yes. It sounds like you won't be able to simply rely on just the HTML output of a page, since there are multiple ways that HTML can render a blank page. You will have to analyze the rendered page somehow. Maybe take a jpg snapshot of it or something programmatically

Comment: Correct: "blank" page is a bad spec. But general: to find out if a page has content of interest or not you need to access it and fetch at least parts of it. -> you need to crawl the site and can't skip it.  But the crawler can stop early if it detects a page with no content of interest and remember it for some time(not crawling it again for some time). Bottom line: a good implemented parser of your crawler will as a sidefect stop parsing early - that again means first defining what you expect(and most likely not what you don't) and stop if not found.

Comment: Maybe: I wrote "most likely" as I actually would do the opposite in a lot of scenarios ;).  In general however it is rather diffuse what one doesn't want and difficult to specify and so you end up with a lot of cases you need to cover and missing a lot of others you didn't think of.  So defining what you want is "usually" simpler as you know that and less errorprone. Comments of @RussJ and your answers indicate a likelyhood that defining what you want(what content is of interesst) instead of what you don't("blank" - what is blank?) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to detect blank web pages depends on its size (below 3 KB) and by scanning the content. Firstly I download the HTML content via `URLConnection` and store it in memory.

```
public ArrayList<String> captureHtmlTags(String inputUrl) {
        ArrayList<String> readWebsiteHTMLTags = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(inputUrl);
            try {
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                // open the stream and assign it into buffered reader..
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                if (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {

                    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(inputLine);
                        readWebsiteHTMLTags.add(String.valueOf(doc));
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    readWebsiteHTMLTags.size();
                } else {
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return readWebsiteHTMLTags;
    }
```

Then using `iText` 7 library I convert read **HTML into PDF** and scan for text contents.

```
public String convertWebsiteToPdf(ArrayList<String> htmlCode) {
        String generateHtmlPage = null;
        String fileLocation = CONST_FILE_PATH; // path to save the PDFs
        generateHtmlPage = htmlCode.toString();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            try {
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
                HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(generateHtmlPage, fileOutputStream);
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return fileLocation;
    }
```

If no content found along with the low size of file, I consider it as a Blank web page.

It worked out finally.